# How to host Spring Webservice REST

Tags: json, spring, web-services, rest, wsdl

This is my first Webservice application.
I need to know how to host it
I have Spring REST Webservice.
I can access succesfully my xml and JSON result in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/lms-mobile/lead/newLeads/last7days
```

Using Tomcat server.
Now this webservice going to be used in some mobile app. So what should be my next steps to make it available.Please help me with process.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your rest web application using cloud services. You can use Amazon EC2 instances to host your application. Setup your database, tomcat server and deploy your app. Your instance will have a public ip, using which you can expose your API's.

Suppose ec2 instance ip is `instanceip`.

1. Setup apache tomcat on ec2 instance
2. export your war file to webapps folder of tomcat server
3. deploy war file
4. Test if it's working using URL `http://instanceip:8080/lms-mobile/lead/newLeads/last7days`